# Servlet Exception - getOutputStream() has already been called for this response

Tags: servlets

In my servlet

an exeception thrown as

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
```

help me to solve this problem

thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit your question following the recommendations in http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This will happen if a call is made to `ServletResponse.getWriter()` when an `OutputStream` has already been created for the response. Only one of `getWriter()` or `getOutputStream()` can be used to write a response body, not both.

Take a look at the stack trace associated with the exception to see if this is the case. Then, if you are trying to write character data use (only) `getWriter()` or for a binary response use `getOutputStream()`.

Comment: @silver_planet in a JSP output is always made of characters (HTML) so you'll always use a Writer (specifically a `JspWriter`), that is the `out` built-in object.