# getting error "getOutputStream() has already been called for this response"

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, spring-mvc, download

I am showing report on some event.I want controller to show popup for save and open .

I already set file in response , after setting response i am returning view.

Now my question is,

I am getting error " java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response"

In my **controller class** i have written following code :

......some Code.......

```
InputStream is =
        new FileInputStream(new File("c:/reports/test_jasper.pdf"));
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=\"test_jasper.pdf\"");
            OutputStream opStream = response.getOutputStream();
            IOUtils.copy(is, opStream);
            response.flushBuffer();
            HttpServletResponse response1 = new HttpServletResponse();

        
        
        model.addAttribute(ABC, new abc());

        model.addAttribute(DEF, new def());
        return SOME_VIEW;
```

**Frameworks :**

Spring-MVC,Hibernate

**Exception :**

java.lang.IllegalStateException: getOutputStream() has already been called for this response

**Desired O/P :**
I want response to show popup for file , and want browser to redirect to some other view.

Comment: `IOUtils.copy(is, opStream);` must try to close the response's output stream you passed after operation. Which is throwing the exception.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1437858/1130032

Comment: @ Jerry: What is the solution...?????

Comment: @Thihara: I tried "response.getOutputStream().close();" then also showing same error

Comment: Your code makes no sense: either you want the response to be a stream of bytes representing a PDF file, or you want the response to be an HTML page generated by the view. It can't be both at the same time.

Comment: yes i did it.@JBNizet: I wanted both response stream as well view.

Comment: That's just not possible. HTTP doesn't work like that.

Comment: I did it using @ Responsebody . Am i doing anything wrong.....?? It's working fine after writing @ Responsebody .

Comment: as per my knowledge @ Responsebody indicates that a method return value should be bound to the web response body

Answer (score 1):

During the request processing both `HttpServletResponse.getWriter()`  and  `HttpServletResponse.getOutputStream()`  are being called. And as per the spec, it is illegal to use both OutputStream and Writer.

The exception you are getting is being thrown while trying to invoje `HttpServletResponse.getWriter()` somewhere else/